# is it required to enable use ble capability from xcode to use ble functions

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it required to enable use ble capability from xcode to use ble functions?

![capabitye][1]

on my app i can use bluetooth but other apps/users cant use bluetooth is responseless
image is for reference. i want to enable backgrundmodes>use ble
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcTDl.png

Comment: Which capability are you referring to? I think you just need to add the correct keys into the plist. For more see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth)

Comment: background modes> use ble, which i didnt add capability to app, other phones cant use bluetooth even the apps has bluetooth permission

Comment: without give capability to  backgroundmodes>"USE BLE ,"  
why other phones cant use bluetooth? my question is this.

Comment: I think what you and I said are identical. Because if you add that capability then the only diff that is created for the project is addition to its plist. This is the diff I got after I changed it in the capabilities: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp4Lg.png. Try it. You'll see both create similar diffs

Comment: already added ble permission into info.plist but capabilities are different for app identifier, every com.app.identifier on apple dev has online permisions like notfifications,, so my question is if i dont add capabilities online,,, other users cant reach ble functionalities=_?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just knew how to add the plist/capability thing. BLE isn't my expertise. Maybe you have different OS versions. I'd just try adding logs and see where it fails.